# How to enable idp signout flow while creating identity provider in AWS Cognito?

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I am using [CreateIdentityProvider](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_CreateIdentityProvider.html) API to **create the Identity provider from my aws-sdk**.

> What parameter i should pass in the params value to enable idp sign
>   out flow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the parameter name from [describe-identity-provider](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cognito-idp/describe-identity-provider.html) API.

We can enable the **IdpSignOut** using aws-sdk API called [CreateIdentityProvider](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_CreateIdentityProvider.html#CognitoUserPools-CreateIdentityProvider-request-IdpIdentifiers)

Parameter:

```
"ProviderDetails": {
    "IDPSignout": "true",
}
```